# setState in useEffect loops the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Why am I getting infinite loop error? React refers to the line marked with `*`:

```js
function Blog() {
    const [blog, setBlog] = useState({});
    const query = useQuery();

    async function takeBlog(query) {
        const _data = await (await fetch(`${root}/api/blog/${query}`)).json();
        console.log(_data.blog)
        setBlog(_.get(_data, 'blog', {}));  // *
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        takeBlog(query);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="blog_page">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="top">
                </div>
                <div className="other ab">
                    <div className="left">
                        <Navbar active='blogs' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="right">
                        <Posts posts={_.get(blog, 'articles', [])} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: Not an answer directly, but based on what you have, I'm not sure you even need all of the complexity of a `useState` and `useEffect` hook. It appears as if `blog` never changes and `takeBlog` is only ever called once. Couldn't this just be: 

`const query = useQuery();`
`const _data = await (await fetch(`${root}/api/blog/${query}`)).json();`
`const blog = _.get(_data, 'blog', {});`

And then remove the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks entirely.

Edit: apologies for terrible comment formatting.

Comment: @Tom, Most likely, the component will become larger and will include state variables, so in any case, I will have to return to this implementation. In addition, the official documentation says to do exactly this in the case of requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function Blog() {
    const [blog, setBlog] = useState({});
    const query = useQuery();

    async function takeBlog(query) {
        const _data = await (await fetch(`${root}/api/blog/${query}`)).json();
        console.log(_data.blog)
        setBlog(_.get(_data, 'blog', {}));  // *
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      const keys = Object.keys(blog);
      if (!keys.length) {
        takeBlog(query);
      }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="blog_page">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="top">
                </div>
                <div className="other ab">
                    <div className="left">
                        <Navbar active='blogs' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="right">
                        <Posts posts={_.get(blog, 'articles', [])} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Blog;
```

Check for blog state varibale in useEffect as a condition